# Set points of polyline programmatically (C#, vvvv/SVG-Library)

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, svg

I'm using this curious [SVG-Library](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG) for C# and I'd like to create some SVG's. I am able to draw a simple polyline with some fix points:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <polyline stroke="red" stroke-width="2" points="230,180 235,199 ..."/>
</svg>
```

Now, how can I add points (respectively attributes) programmatically to my polyline? Are there any good tutroials?

There is no Documentation nor could I find something helpful. If you colud help be, I would be very grateful

Comment: I am haven't worked over SVG, but logically you can change the xml (either using LINQ to XML or simple xmlDocument )and redraw the polylines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow these steps to manage that:
1) you'll need a list with some values (ex. Y-Values) 
2) add every value form this list to a polyline and dont forget the X-Value as well as the space between the points
3) generate your chart with `using Stream` and `File.Create(path)`
4) create a new svgdocument and set width, height and viewbox.
5) create a svgpolyline and add it as a group to your svgdocument with coordinates from your polyline
6) call `Write(stream)` on your svgdocument. It will create a file at your before setted `path`